# SVG set attributeName="visibility" works first time, but not after that

Tags: animation, svg, set, visible

In the following, the text (CLICK ME) is supposed to reappear .5 seconds after the `morphMe` animation ends. (See the last line of code other than closing tags)

It works fine, making the text appear the first time the animation ends. But it does not ever work after that. I can't figure why it works only once;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
  <text id="startText" >CLICK ANYWHERE</text> 
</defs>

 <rect id="startMe" x="0"  y="0" width="300" height="300" fill= "red"> </rect>

<g transform="translate(50, 50)">
<path d="M 100,0  200,200  0,200  50,100 z;" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="32"  stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="68">

 <animate id="morphMe"
 restart="always"
 begin="startMe.click;startText.click;click;"
 attributeName="d" 
 dur="2s" 
 calcmode="spline"
 repeatCount="2"
 values=
 "M 100,0   200,200   0,200  50,100 z  ;
 M 200,0   200,200   0,200  00,0 z  ;
 M 200,200   0,200   0,0  200,0  z ;
 M 200,0   200,200   0,200  00,0  z ;
 M 100,0   200,200   0,200  50,100 z:"
 keyTimes="0; .25; .5; .75; 1"
 keySplines="1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 1;"
 fill="freeze"
 />
</path>
</g>
<g>
  <use xlink:href="#startText" x="150" y="160" style="font-size: 18pt; fill: white; stroke: none; font-family: Rockwell; text-anchor: middle;"/> 
  <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden" begin="morphMe.begin"/> 
  <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible" begin="morphMe.end+.5s"/>

</g>
</svg
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got `repeatCount="2"` so change that to `repeatCount="indefinite"` and that should ensure your animation doesn't stop.

See the docs here; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/repeatCount

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems.

- A semicolon has been mistyped as a colon in the animation
- Fractional time offsets in SMIL must begin with a leading 0 (although Chrome does not enforce this)

I'd also probably just make the text and shape pointer-events: none since you don't want to manage clicks on them and just process clicks on the rect. I've also made that change below.

After that everything seems to work (at least on Firefox where I'm testing it).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
  <text id="startText" pointer-events="none">CLICK ANYWHERE</text> 
</defs>

 <rect id="startMe" x="0"  y="0" width="300" height="300" fill= "red"> </rect>

<g transform="translate(50, 50)" pointer-events="none">
<path d="M 100,0  200,200  0,200  50,100 z;" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="32"  stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="68">

 <animate id="morphMe"
 restart="always"
 begin="startMe.click"
 attributeName="d" 
 dur="2s" 
 calcmode="spline"
 repeatCount="2"
 values=
 "M 100,0   200,200   0,200  50,100 z  ;
 M 200,0   200,200   0,200  00,0 z  ;
 M 200,200   0,200   0,0  200,0  z ;
 M 200,0   200,200   0,200  00,0  z ;
 M 100,0   200,200   0,200  50,100 z;"
 keyTimes="0; .25; .5; .75; 1"
 keySplines="1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 1; 1 0 1 1;"
 fill="freeze"
 />
</path>
</g>
<g>
  <use xlink:href="#startText" x="150" y="160" style="font-size: 18pt; fill: white; stroke: none; font-family: Rockwell; text-anchor: middle;"/> 
  <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden" begin="morphMe.begin"/> 
  <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible" begin="morphMe.end+0.5s"/>

</g>
</svg
```

Comment: The pointer-events object is beyond what I've studied so far (I am still in the newbie shallows.) I'll look into it. While your changes have it now working for me in Firefox (thanks!) it still has the same behavior in Chrome: the text reappears after the first time through the animation, but it never comes back after subsequent animation runs. This is pretty disappointing, as it appears that support for SVG is very uneven, and I can't see anything wrong with the syntax. I'm still at the point that it could be that I'm doing something a bit illegal though.

Comment: You've found a Chrome bug then. There's nothing wrong with the syntax in my answer. You can report Chrome bugs here: https://crbug.com/wizard